# Cross Validation Metrics for H2o

Tags: r, cross-validation, h2o

I'm having a hard time understanding why the output for various metrics on my models differs when I use h2o.

For example,  if I use 'h2o.grid' then the logloss measure is *different* when I look at the mean model$cross_validation_metrics_summary.  It is the same as   model$cross_validation_metrics_summary.   What is the reasoning behind this difference?  What one should I report on?

```
library(mlbench) 
  library(h2o)
 data(Sonar)

h2o.init() Sonarhex <- as.h2o(Sonar) h2o.grid("gbm", grid_id = "gbm_grid_id0", x = c(1:50), y = 'Class',
         training_frame = Sonarhex, hyper_params = list(ntrees = 50, learn_rate = c(.1, .2, .3)), nfolds = 5, seed=1234)

grid <- h2o.getGrid("gbm_grid_id0", sort_by = 'logloss')

first_model = h2o.getModel(grid@model_ids[[1]]) first_model@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary first_model@model$cross_validation_metrics
```

Comment: Please review the source code I was not able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This inconsistency is an issue that has been documented and explained [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4975) and will be resolved in a future release.  The `model$cross_validation_metrics_summary` metrics are the correct CV metrics.  The metrics that appear in the Grid table or by using the utility functions like `h2o.logloss(model, xval = TRUE)` are slightly different because they aggregate the CV predictions and then compute the loss (instead of computing the loss separately across K folds and then taking the average).  This can lead to slight numerical differences.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the following function

```
def sort_grid(grid,metric):
#input: grid and metric to order
if metric == 'accuracy':
    id = 0
elif metric == 'auc':
    id = 1
elif metric=='err':
    id = 2
elif metric == 'err_count':
    id=3
elif metric=='f0point5':
    id=4
elif metric=='f1':
    id=5
elif metric =='f2':
    id=6
elif metric =='lift_top_group':
    id=7
elif metric == 'logloss':
    id=8
elif metric == 'max_per_class_error':
    id=9
elif metric == 'mcc':
    metric=9
elif metric =='mena_per_class_accuracy':
    id=10
elif metric == 'mean_per_class_error':
    id=11
elif metric == 'mse':
    id =12
elif metric == 'pr_auc':
    id=13
elif metric == 'precision':
    id=14
elif metric == 'r2':
    id=15
elif metric =='recall':
    id=16
elif metric == 'rmse':
    id = 17
elif metric == 'specificity':
    id = 18
else: 
    return 0

model_ids = []
cross_val_values = []
number_of_models = len(grid.model_ids) 
number_of_models
for i in range(number_of_models):
    modelo_grid = grid[i]
    mean = np.array(modelo_grid.cross_validation_metrics_summary()[[1]])
    cross_val= mean[0][id]
    model_id = grid.model_ids[i]
    model_ids.append(model_id)
    cross_val_values.append(cross_val)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Model_IDs': model_ids, metric: cross_val_values}
)
df = df.sort_values([metric], ascending=False)
best_model = h2o.get_model(df.iloc[0,0])
return df, best_model
#output ordered grid in pandas dataframe and best model
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.